# How expensive are variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance

How expensive are local variables (`var v`), global variables (`window.v`) and cross-global variables (`parent.v`) in JavaScript, in the major browsers? Has anyone performed any good tests on this one?

Comment: Expensive in terms of what? Performance? Memory? Also, what do the variables *contain*? I'm sure a variable containing a single integer is not very expensive, but one containing a large array would be more so...

Comment: Curse this variable inflation!  I guess I'll have to reuse some of my variables to save money...

Comment: damn it. not three fiddy

Comment: @codeka: Yes, in terms of performance, memory and whatever else _you_ can think of.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ignoring interpreter/parser pros and cons, all that matters is how much the runtime has to look at parts of the scope chain.

Consider this simple example:

```
foo = 42;         // implicitly window.foo; cost: 2
var bar = 3;      // cost: 1

function woot(a) {
    a;            // cost: 1
    bar;          // cost: 2
    foo;          // cost: 3

    var other = 9;// cost: 1

    other;        // cost: 1

    a.something;  // cost: 2
    foo.win.fail.arg.func(a.something).thing = 0; // cost: 8 + 2
}

woot(bar);        // cost: 2 + 1
```

Remember that functions share the same namespace as variables (*I think*) and act like variables with regards to resolution.

There is no additional cost to using `foo['bar']` instead of `foo.bar`, except perhaps optimizations by the Javscript engine (though if you're optimizing the latter it should be easy to optimize the former if the contents are literal).

Comment: functions are treated the same as variables in this sense - they are both added to the Variable Object created for the scope.

Comment: @Sean Kisney, Thanks for the clarification.  I know the basics of how Javascript works, but I haven't read the ECMAScript spec or anything.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but very insightful, I never really realized that the cost of a global variable is about three times as much as the cost of a local one. As you say, the parser may and should be irrelevant, as they are improving on a monthly basis these days.

Comment: @Tom, If you have more and more scopes (functions in functions, e.g.), the cost of a global further increases because it's further along the scope chain.  (A lot of scoping is common with much of the jQuery code out there.)

Answer (score 3):

Locally scoped variables will always be present on the local Variable Object, and so will be 'free'.

To reach a global variable while in a scope you will have to traverse the scope chain until reaching the global object, where it will be found on the [[global]] Variable Object.  The cost here depends on the number of scopes in the chain.

When it comes to accessing variables in different windows, now that is a different story.
Most newer browsers isolate each window with its own threads and with its own stack, in order to improve stability, improve garbage collection, and to avoid having one windows thread crash the entire browser.
What this means for variable access is that variables in one window isn't directly accessible to another (on a different stack). So how is this solved?

To take Opera as an example, once one window tries to access another windows variables, Opera will actually pause execution, merge the two stacks and execution environments together, and then continue the execution.
I guess you might say that this is *quite* expensive :)

Comment: Never considered "IPC" in Web pages; nice thought.